# Calculate the Signed Distance Transform of arbitrary polygon

Tags: c++, c++11, computational-geometry

How would you calculate the Signed Distance Function of a polygon, described by an arbitrary set of points. The polygon could be concave or convex. Assume that the points are stored in a `std::vector` with counter-clockwise winding.

[image: Diagram of polygon]

**Update**

Let me be more specific. This is not a sampled function on a grid. I need to be able to detect a sign change along an arbitrary line segment drawn through (not necessarily intersecting) the polygon, without checking individual intersections with each line segment. The problem is, I might have thousands of line segments.

Can anyone think of an efficient way of doing this?

If I can parametrically express the SDF, I can calculate a derivative to accomplish this.

Comment: I would use math.

Comment: what have you done, at the moment?

Comment: So far, I have played with using set operations to create a parametric SDF from different line segments. Constructive Solid Geometry seems like a good starting point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry

The problem is, you end up with a bunch of piecewise equations from the `min` `max` operations. Maybe I could describe the boundary as a smoothly interpolated bezier or something.

Comment: Another option is to use basis functions to approximate the curve. Maybe something like a 2D Taylor Series, but then I will end up with ringing at the sharp corners due to the Gibbs Phenomenon. For this part of the project, sharp features are not essential.

Comment: This is not a good idea for two reasons. 1. Because the sign function, regardless how you evaluate it, has to include the 2N degrees of freedom of the polygon, and will unavoidably require O(N) computation time. 2. Because searching for the changes of signs will require the evaluation of the sign function at several places (minimum 2 but possibly much more), whatever the search algorithm. So the total cost can exceed O(N.M) for M segments.

Comment: Yes. My idea is fundamentally flawed. I am going to try to incorporate it into my level of detail system. I'll also add that I am voxellizing a planet with a 2D version of the Adaptive Dual Contouring of Hermite Data. http://www.frankpetterson.com/publications/dualcontour/dualcontour.pdf. The first step uses tiles with elevations calculated with a rough plate tectonic simulation on a planetary scale.

Comment: The tiles are radial to the planet centre. I foresee using anywhere from 256 to 1024 of these radial tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news: in the worst case, a line segment can intersect the polygon in `N` points, and this can arise for all `M` line segments. So in the worst case, exhaustive comparison of the segments vs. the sides is unavoidable. This goes in favor of the brute-force approach.

Fortunately, output-sensitive solutions are known for the problem of the intersection of `N` line segments, using the sweepline approach. The complexity can be lowered to `O((N+K) log N)` or `O(N log N + K)` where `K` is the number of intersections found.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly rotate all the points so the line is parallel with the x axis. Then translate so that the line is the x axis. Then as a test integrate. The area under a straight line x0y0 x1y1 is pretty simple to calculate. You can sum all the expressions to get the indefinite integral, or signed area, which should be independent of axis (because points under the curve subtract). Now to answer the specific question, sort in x to enable you to find the point value at a given x. So create two "events", section start, and section "end" with a pointer or reference back to the start event. Then to get the distance transform at any point, we calculate all the events the cross the x of interest. If you want piecewise functions to each event interval, that's actually slightly easier as you can pass through the queue from start to end.